# Creating an .xlsx with a db connection

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, jxls

I am creating export files with Apache POI (as .xls so far) with this code successfully

```
Connection conn = ...// get database connection in some way
Map beans = new HashMap();
ReportManager rm = new ReportManagerImpl( conn, beans );
beans.put("rm", rm);
InputStream is = 
              new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("reportTemplate.xls"));
XLSTransformer transformer = new XLSTransformer();
HSSFWorkbook resultWorkbook = transformer.transformXLS(is, beans);
```

retrieved from [here](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/sqlreporting.html). But now my question is: is there a possibility to get the exact same thing for .xlsx? I am not able to find anything on the web concerning this, but it would surprise me if I am the first one needing this.

Comment: You can use [Aspose For Java](http://www.aspose.com/java/excel-component.aspx) for creating .xlsx files.

Comment: jXLS is open source so you could modify it to return a `XSSFWorkbook`.

Comment: Where does `XLSTransformer` come from? It doesn't look like a standard part of Apache POI?

Comment: Unfortunately I am bound to JXLS, so i can't change that. Modifying the source is an option, but would be nice if there is already a solution. The XLSTransformer comes from here http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.jxls/jxls-core/0.9.2/net/sf/jxls/transformer/XLSTransformer.java

Comment: poi supports `.xlsx`. You need to use an XSSFWorkbook. Read more about it here: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/

Comment: Yeah I know that already thanks, but I need access to a database and "transformXLS" delievers that only for .xls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should upgrade your jXLS.  Support for .xlsx files was added in version 1.0, according to [the project's news page](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.jxls/jxls-core/1.0.2/net/sf/jxls/transformer/XLSTransformer.java#XLSTransformer.transformXLS%28java.io.InputStream%2Cjava.util.Map%29).  The current version of jXLS is 1.0.2 and it has [the `transformXLS` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.jxls/jxls-core/1.0.2/net/sf/jxls/transformer/XLSTransformer.java#XLSTransformer.transformXLS%28java.io.InputStream%2Cjava.util.Map%29) returning a `Workbook` object, not a `HSSFWorkbook`.

```
public org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook transformXLS(
    InputStream is, Map beanParams)
```

Comment: I didn't see that. Thanks! I try that one out as soon as I get back to my code and tell you about my result.

Comment: I tested it now. I guess it would work for others, but I hit the next problem concerning this part:  `public int getExternalSheetIndex(String workbookName, String sheetName) {
  throw new RuntimeException("not implemented yet");
 }`      

Seems like this appears calling XSSFEvaluationWorkbook to calculate formulas. But even if I don't use any it fails. Thanks for the help anyway